# Visual Studio - is there a way to generate a warning if a return value is not checked?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

We have an in-house API written in C# where many of the methods have return values, typically bool's or ints, which sometimes the callers ignore.   The return values are there for a reason, e.g., to indicate a problem or result of some kind, so we want to encourage the callers to actually check the result rather than just blithely assuming the method worked as expected, only to have things go bad farther downstream.

Is there a way to use the Visual Studio compiler to enforce checking return values by flagging calls, using a warning or error, when a caller fails to check the return value of a non-void method?

Comment: You could do something super dumb and use `out` parameters everywhere.

Comment: It sounds like you are returning error codes.  Why are you not using exceptions to indicate failed states?

Comment: Maybe tools like StyleCop or FxCop could help? I didn't use them personally, but I assume it might be a good use case for those two.

Comment: Also, Roslyn analyzers are perfect for this sort of thing and are [surprisingly easy to write](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2015/04/30/learn-roslyn-now-part-10-introduction-to-analyzers/).

Comment: @Kirk Woll Because they aren't just catastrophic failures.   For example we have some calls that establish network connections over noisy WiFi networks, with pieces of industrial machinery, and the return value is the number of tries it took before successful.  A rising number could be a sign of trouble but it doesn't equate to failure.   But let's say we threw an exception -  wouldn't it be the same problem?  Can we get the compiler to flag when a call that throws an exception isn't wrapped in a try/catch?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "checking return values"? Assigning them to a (potentially unused) variable, using them in an if-statement, something else?

Comment: @Matthias, I'm pretty sure he means that the return value is consumed in some fashion and not simply treated as a void method.

Comment: @user316117, fair enough.  You should look into the analzyer idea.  It's pretty fun to write and once you get it working it's really satisfying to see the red squigglies in your editor to indicate the problem.  It can even fail the build.

Comment: I'd settle for just assigning it to a (potentially) unused variable because that might still put the thought that there's a return value to deal with in the programmer's mind.

Comment: @user316117 The reason an exception is better is because it won't *silently* fail. It will fail very loudly if nobody catches it. However, if it's just number of attempts, why not just log the number from within the method if it gets too high? That seems much better than relying on all callers to care about the value.

Comment: @31eee384  But that's just one example.  My point is that they are not voids but the compiler doesn't seem to have a way to acknowledge that.

Comment: If you somehow enforce a requirement that users consume every result from every function you are going to end up with a poorly performing API.  The reason I say that is because all of your users are going to end up wrapping all of your functions so that they can ignore the results in their real code.  They will let the wrapper handle getting around your rules.  So, if you want the users to have an extra layer in their code then proceed with this venture.

Comment: Despite that  I'd also opt for eceptions, how about this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182273.aspx I cannot verify it at the moment, otherwise I would make it an answer.

Comment: It looks like the Roslyn analyzer is for VS 2015.  We're using VS 2012 and VS 2013 that's that's probably not an option.  But I assume if there was a straightforward solution to this someone would have posted it as an answer by now, so it looks like we're just going to have to crack the whip on the programmers instead of having the compiler give them a gentle nudge.

Comment: @user316117 It seems to me that, so far, for each example of why you'd do this there's a better way to get the desired result. That suggests to me that it isn't a useful thing to do (pending a great example of course). Maybe you're best off posting single examples to get the best answer for each situation?

Comment: @user316117 The link I posted in my previous comment is about a warning that should be produced by FxCop, which can be used with VS2012 (and even older). Maybe you want to give it a try (and using FxCop wouldn't be bad idea in general).

Comment: @Matthias I think your answer may be as close as possible to what is being asked.  I'm not sure if it guarantees that the code actually does anything with the return value, however.  A programmer could just set a variable to the result and then still ignore it, I guess.

Comment: @stephen.vakil Yep, and a programmer could also write an empty catch block. That's what code reviews (by humans) are adressing, and actively working around compiler warnings requires more action and hence could be easier detected in a code review.

Comment: when you have non-fatal results you want to return, you can do it by raising an event (like status) instead of an error.  they can still ignore it, though.

Comment: At one of my previous job sites, the code often ignored return values from calls. These calls were treated like they returned void. The original developers were only interested in the return values in a small handful of cases. When Coverity (a static analysis tool) was brought in to scan all new code changes, it yelled about all of those unchecked return values. That led to a lot of money spent to change those treated void calls to catch their return--- and then ignore the caught value. So money spent and time lost just to make a warning go away on function returns no one cared about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to encourage better practices, use exceptions. That'll at least make them aware something is happening if they simply neglected to do anything. If they bury the exception, they bury it. But it requires an active decision to do so.

Basically any time your code can go "I'm at a point where there's a problem and the solution is either absent or ambiguous" is when to throw.

Besides throwing exceptions, when you return control back to the caller, there's nothing programmatically you can do to enforce what they do afterwards.

Comment: It isn't always better to throw an exception. For example, all .TryParse methodes (int.TryParse()) doesn't throw an exception when the input can't be parsed to an int. Most of the time yoiu should check wether the parsing was succesful, but in some circumstansions the is isn't. eg when the default value of the result is the value you need when the input can't be parsed

Comment: The use of TryParse makes sense if you have the expectation that it might fail and have a backup plan (for example, a default value). However, if other people are calling your code, and you don't want the responsibility of handling an invalid input value, it's still more useful to just use Parse and let the exception bubble up to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

There already is an compiler-warning for this, [MSDN][1]

[1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182273.aspx is you use FX cop

Comment: This claims to check only objects or HRESULTs, so if you return a plain int it doesn't appear it would work.

Comment: while this answers the users question, it should not be the practice of telling calling code something bad/unexpected happened